# Entity to LINQ upload CSV file where single rows can have multiple values in columns

Tags: c#, linq, csv, entity

I'm currently working on parsing a csv file that was exported by another application. This application exported the data in a strange way. This export is from accoutning and it looks similar to this..

[image]

I'm trying to figure out a way to read the csv file, then split up the multiple 'All Accounts' values and 'Amt' Values so that M200 and 300.89 is another entry, M300 and 400.54 are another entry, and M400 and 100.00 are another entry. So after inserting this single row into the database, I should actually have 4 rows like so..

[image]

This is how I'm currently reading and inserting into the database.

```
List<RawData> data = new List<RawData>();

try
{
   string text = File.ReadAllText(lblFileName.Text);
   string[] lines = text.Split('\n');
   int total = 0, reduced = 0;
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
      RawData temp = new RawData(line);
      total++;
      if (!(temp.FirstAccount.Length == 0 || temp.FirstAccount == "1ST-ACCT-NO"))
      {
         reduced++;
         data.Add(temp);
       }
    }
 }
 catch (IOException ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Unable to read file. " + ex.ToString());
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }

  try
  {
     foreach (RawData rData in data)
     {
         tCarsInTransit cit = new tCarsInTransit
         {
             FIRST_ACCT_NO = rData.FirstAccount,
             ACCOUNT_NO_DV = rData.AccountNoDv,
             ACCT_NO = rData.AcctNo,
             ACCT_NO_L = rData.AccNoL,
             ACCT_NUM_DV = rData.AcctNumDv,
             ACCT_PFX = rData.AcctPfx,
             ACCT_PFX_PRT = rData.AcctPfxPrt,
             ACCT_TYPE_DV = rData.AcctTypeDv,
             ADV_NO = rData.AdvNo,
             ALL_PRT_FLAG = rData.AllPrtFlag,
             AMT = rData.Amt,
             AMT_GLE = rData.AmtGle,
             BASE_GLE = rData.BaseGle,
             CNT_CAT = rData.CntCat,
             COLD_PRT_FLAG = rData.ColdPrtFlag,
             COST_DV = rData.CostDv,
             COST_OVRD_FLAG_DV = rData.CostOvrdFlagDv,
             CR_ACCT_DV = rData.CrAcctDv,
             CR_ACCT_DV_GLE = rData.CrAcctDvGle,
             CROSS_POSTING_FLAG = rData.CrossPostingFlag,
             CROSS_POST_CAT = rData.CrossPostCat,
             CTRL_NO = rData.CtrlNo,
             CTRL_TYPE_DV = rData.CtrlTypeDv,
             DESC_REQD_DV = rData.DescReqdDv,
             DR_ACCT_DV = rData.DrAcctDv,
             GL_DIST_ACCT_DV = rData.GLDistAcctDv,
             GL_DIST_DV = rData.GLDistDv,
             GRP_NO_DV = rData.GrpNoDv,
             ID_PORT_DATE_TIME_FMT_CAT = rData.IdPortDateTimeFmtCat,
             INACTIVITY_DV = rData.InactivityDv,
             JOIN_COL = rData.JoinCol,
             JRNL_DATE = rData.JrnlDate,
             JRNL_PFX = rData.JrnlPfx
          };

          tCIT.tCarsInTransits.Add(cit);

          tCIT.SaveChanges();

          lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
          lblMessage.Text = "Finished uploading. ";
       }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
       foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
             eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
          foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
          {
             Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                 ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
          }
        }
        throw;
     }
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this. The above currently inserts the csv file into Sql Server the exact way the csv file was exported. Any ideas would greatly be appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the RawData class.

```
class RawData
{
    public string FirstAccount { get; set; }
    public string AccountNoDv { get; set; }
    public string AcctNo { get; set; }
    public string AccNoL { get; set; }
    public string AcctNumDv { get; set; }
    public string AcctPfx { get; set; }
    public string AcctPfxPrt { get; set; }
    public string AcctTypeDv { get; set; }
    public string AdvNo { get; set; }
    public string AllPrtFlag { get; set; }
    public string Amt { get; set; }
    public string AmtGle { get; set; }
    public string BaseGle { get; set; }
    public string CntCat { get; set; }
    public string ColdPrtFlag { get; set; }
    public string CostDv { get; set; }
    public string CostOvrdFlagDv { get; set; }
    public string CrAcctDv { get; set; }
    public string CrAcctDvGle { get; set; }
    public string CrossPostingFlag { get; set; }
    public string CrossPostCat { get; set; }
    public string CtrlNo { get; set; }
    public string CtrlTypeDv { get; set; }
    public string DescReqdDv { get; set; }
    public string DrAcctDv { get; set; }
    public string GLDistAcctDv { get; set; }
    public string GLDistDv { get; set; }
    public string GrpNoDv { get; set; }
    public string IdPortDateTimeFmtCat { get; set; }
    public string InactivityDv { get; set; }
    public string JoinCol { get; set; }
    public string JrnlDate { get; set; }
    public string JrnlPfx { get; set; }

    public RawData(string csvString)
    {
        string[] citData = csvString.Replace(", ", "").Replace(".,", ".").Split(',');

        try
        {
            FirstAccount = citData[0];
            AccountNoDv = citData[1];
            AcctNo = citData[2];
            AccNoL = citData[3];
            AcctNumDv = citData[4];
            AcctPfx = citData[5];
            AcctPfxPrt = citData[6];
            AcctTypeDv = citData[7];
            AdvNo = citData[8];
            AllPrtFlag = citData[9];              
            Amt = citData[10];
            AmtGle = citData[11];
            BaseGle = citData[12];
            CntCat = citData[13];
            ColdPrtFlag = citData[14];
            CostDv = citData[15];
            CostOvrdFlagDv = citData[16];
            CrAcctDv = citData[17];
            CrAcctDvGle = citData[18];
            CrossPostingFlag = citData[19];
            CrossPostCat = citData[20];
            CtrlNo = citData[21];
            CtrlTypeDv = citData[22];
            DescReqdDv = citData[23];
            DrAcctDv = citData[24];
            GLDistAcctDv = citData[25];
            GLDistDv = citData[26];
            GrpNoDv = citData[27];
            IdPortDateTimeFmtCat = citData[28];
            InactivityDv = citData[29];
            JoinCol = citData[30];
            JrnlDate = citData[31];
            JrnlPfx = citData[32];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong. " + ex.ToString());           
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: AllAccounts in the images is acutally 'AccountNoDv' and there are actually many different fields that have multiples like 'AccountNoDv'(AllAccounts) but we might be removing those as this is not a final export. As of right now the two fields I'm worried most about are AccountNoDv and Amt.

Comment: Could you provide us with the definition of the RawData class, or at least its constructor?

Comment: Yes I can, I'm an idiot for not posting that.

Comment: Thanks, now which field of the RawData class holds the value for the AllAccounts column?

Comment: Also something I forgot to mention eh? I'll make another edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
      RawData temp = new RawData(line);
      var AllAccounts = temp.AccountNoDv.split(' ');
      var Amts = temp.Amt.split(' ');
      if (AllAccounts.Length() == Amts.Length() && Amts.Length() > 1) {
        // We have multiple values!
        reduced++;
        for (int i = 0; i < AllAccounts.Length(); i++) {
          RawData temp2 = RawDataCopy(temp); // Copy the RawData object
          temp2.AccountNoDv = AllAccounts[i];
          temp2.Amt = Amts[i];
          total++;
          data.Add(temp2);
        }
      }
      else {
        total++;
        if (!(temp.FirstAccount.Length == 0 || temp.FirstAccount == "1ST-ACCT-NO"))
        {
           reduced++;
           data.Add(temp);
         }
       }
    }
```

And:

```
private RawData RawDataCopy(RawData copyfrom) {
  // Write a function here that returns an exact copy from the one provided
  // You might have to create a parameterless constructor for RawData
  RawData RawDataCopy = new RawData();
  RawDataCopy.FirstAccount = copyfrom.FirstAccount;
  RawDataCopy.AccountNoDv = copyfrom.AccountNoDv;
  RawDataCopy.AcctNo = copyfrom.AcctNo;
  // . . . . . . . .
  RawDataCopy.JrnlPfx = copyfrom.JrnlPfx;
  return RawDataCopy;
}
```

Then also add a parameterless constructor to your RawData class:

```
public RawData()
{
}
```

Perhaps it would be sexier to implement the `ICloneable` interface and call the `Clone()` function instead of the `RawDataCopy` function, but it gets the idea across.

Comment: I will give this a shot and see what I can come up with. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I haven't quite figured it out yet.. unfortunately, are you able to go more in depth on the 2nd part of your answer? The 'private RawData RawDataCopy(RawData copyform)'

Comment: You're the man. This works pretty well, only if the data wasn't so botched... I just realized that if there are 20 values in 'AllAccounts', there may not be 20 values in 'Amt' so.. this is a total bummer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! Would you mind checking my answer as the correct one if you're not planning to expand your question?

Answer (score 0):

In Linq you can use SelectMany to increase the number of elements in a list.  Here is a rough example of how this could be done.  I make the assumption that the number of sub elements in AllAccounts and Amt is the same.  A more robust solution would check for these issues.

So after you have loaded your data list:

```
var expandedData =
   data.SelectMany(item => 
      // split amount (will just return one item if no spaces)
      item.Amt.Split(" ".ToCharArray())
      // join this to the split of all accounts
      .Zip(item.AllAccounts.Split(" ".ToCharArray()),
      // return the joined item as a new anon object
       (a,b) => new { amt=a, all=b }),
      // take the original list item and the anon object and return our new item
      (full,pair) => { full.Amt = pair.amt; full.AllAccounts = pair.all; return full; }));
```

You will now have a list of your data items with the multiple items expanded into the list.

I don't have test data to test so I might have some minor typos -- but I put in lots of comments to make the Linq as clear as possible.

---

Here is is simple example I wrote in LinqPad for myself to make sure I understood how SelectMany worked:

```
string [] list = { "a b c d","e","f g" };

var result = list.SelectMany((e) =>
             e.Split(" ".ToCharArray()), 
             (o,item) => new { org = o, item = item}).Dump();
```